# Cython function taking more time than pure python

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am trying to accelerate my code and this part of it is giving me problems,

I tried to use Cython and then followed the advise given [here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html) but my pure python function performs better than both the cython and cython_optimized ones

The cython code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False) 

def compute_cython(u, PorosityProfile, DensityIceProfile, DensityDustProfile, DensityProfile):

    DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI = 250.0, 633.0, 2.513, -2.2e-3, -2.8e-6   
    IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH =  273.16, 1.843e5, 1.6357e8, 3.5519e9, 1.6670e2,  6.4650e4, 1.6935e6

    delta = u-DustJ
    result_dust = DustF+DustG*delta+DustH*delta**2+DustI*(delta**3);

    x= u/IceI;
    result_ice = (x**3)*(IceC+IceD*(x**2)+IceE*(x**6))/(1+IceF*(x**2)+IceG*(x**4)+IceH*(x**8))

    return (DensityIceProfile*result_ice+DensityDustProfile*result_dust)/DensityProfile


def compute_cythonOptimized(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] u, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] PorosityProfile, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] DensityIceProfile, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] DensityDustProfile, np.ndarray DensityProfile):

    assert u.dtype == DTYPE
    assert PorosityProfile.dtype == DTYPE
    assert DensityIceProfile.dtype == DTYPE
    assert DensityDustProfile.dtype == DTYPE
    assert DensityProfile.dtype == DTYPE

    cdef float DustJ = 250.0
    cdef float DustF = 633.0  
    cdef float DustG = 2.513 
    cdef float DustH = -2.2e-3   
    cdef float DustI = -2.8e-6 
    cdef float IceI =  273.16
    cdef float IceC =  1.843e5 
    cdef float IceD =  1.6357e8 
    cdef float IceE =  3.5519e9 
    cdef float IceF =  1.6670e2 
    cdef float IceG =  6.4650e4
    cdef float IceH =  1.6935e6

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] delta = u-DustJ
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] result_dust = DustF+DustG*delta+DustH*delta**2+DustI*(delta**3);

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] x= u/IceI;
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] result_ice = (x**3)*(IceC+IceD*(x**2)+IceE*(x**6))/(1+IceF*(x**2)+IceG*(x**4)+IceH*(x**8))

    return (DensityIceProfile*result_ice+DensityDustProfile*result_dust)/DensityProfile
```

I then run the following commands:

```
def compute_python(u, PorosityProfile, DensityIceProfile, DensityDustProfile, DensityProfile):

    DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI = 250.0, 633.0, 2.513, -2.2e-3, -2.8e-6   
    IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH =  273.16, 1.843e5, 1.6357e8, 3.5519e9, 1.6670e2,  6.4650e4, 1.6935e6

    delta = u-DustJ
    result_dust = DustF+DustG*delta+DustH*delta**2+DustI*(delta**3);

    x= u/IceI;
    result_ice = (x**3)*(IceC+IceD*(x**2)+IceE*(x**6))/(1+IceF*(x**2)+IceG*(x**4)+IceH*(x**8))

    return (DensityIceProfile*result_ice+DensityDustProfile*result_dust)/DensityProfile

import sublimation
import numpy as np

%timeit compute_python(np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100))

%timeit compute_cython(np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100))

%timeit compute_cythonOptimized(np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100),np.random.rand(100))
```

Which results in the following:

For the pure python: `68.9 µs ± 851 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

For the non optimized cython: `68.2 µs ± 685 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

And for the optimized one: `72.7 µs ± 416 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: There's not much to optimize; `numpy` is already doing all the hard work, and it is already written in C. You're just adding a layer of overhead.

Comment: In addition to what chepner said, since you are already in the `numpy` world, consider using `numba`

Comment: Are you measuring the random number generation with the function? I get 46.8µs for the Python version and 3.11µs for a simple Numba version(@numba.njit(fastmath=True). Are your arrays everytime that small (only 100 values)? If not parallelization would also be beneficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A solution using Numba

CodeSurgeon already gave an excellent answer using Cython. In this answer I wan't to show an alternative way using Numba.

I have created three versions. In `naive_numba` I only have added an function decorator. In `improved_Numba` I have manually combined the loops (every vectorized command is actually a loop). In `improved_Numba_p` I have parallelized the function. Please note that there is obviously a Bug not allowing to define constant values when using the pararallel accelerator. It has also be noted that the parallelized version is only beneficial for larger input arrays. But you can also add a small wrapper which calls the single threaded or the parallelized version according to the input array size.

**Code dtype=float64**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time



@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def naive_Numba(u, PorosityProfile, DensityIceProfile, DensityDustProfile, DensityProfile):
  DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI = 250.0, 633.0, 2.513, -2.2e-3, -2.8e-6   
  IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH =  273.16, 1.843e5, 1.6357e8, 3.5519e9, 1.6670e2,  6.4650e4, 1.6935e6

  delta = u-DustJ
  result_dust = DustF+DustG*delta+DustH*delta**2+DustI*(delta**3);

  x= u/IceI;
  result_ice = (x**3)*(IceC+IceD*(x**2)+IceE*(x**6))/(1+IceF*(x**2)+IceG*(x**4)+IceH*(x**8))

  return (DensityIceProfile*result_ice+DensityDustProfile*result_dust)/DensityProfile

#error_model='numpy' sets divison by 0 to NaN instead of throwing a exception, this allows vectorization
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model='numpy')
def improved_Numba(u, PorosityProfile, DensityIceProfile, DensityDustProfile, DensityProfile):
  DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI = 250.0, 633.0, 2.513, -2.2e-3, -2.8e-6   
  IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH =  273.16, 1.843e5, 1.6357e8, 3.5519e9, 1.6670e2,  6.4650e4, 1.6935e6
  res=np.empty(u.shape[0],dtype=u.dtype)

  for i in range(u.shape[0]):
    delta = u[i]-DustJ
    result_dust = DustF+DustG*delta+DustH*delta**2+DustI*(delta**3);

    x= u[i]/IceI
    result_ice = (x**3)*(IceC+IceD*(x**2)+IceE*(x**6))/(1+IceF*(x**2)+IceG*(x**4)+IceH*(x**8))

    res[i]=(DensityIceProfile[i]*result_ice+DensityDustProfile[i]*result_dust)/DensityProfile[i]

  return res

#there is obviously a bug in Numba (declaring const values in the function)
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,error_model='numpy')
def improved_Numba_p(u, PorosityProfile, DensityIceProfile, DensityDustProfile, DensityProfile,DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI,IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH):
  res=np.empty((u.shape[0]),dtype=u.dtype)

  for i in nb.prange(u.shape[0]):
    delta = u[i]-DustJ
    result_dust = DustF+DustG*delta+DustH*delta**2+DustI*(delta**3);

    x= u[i]/IceI
    result_ice = (x**3)*(IceC+IceD*(x**2)+IceE*(x**6))/(1+IceF*(x**2)+IceG*(x**4)+IceH*(x**8))

    res[i]=(DensityIceProfile[i]*result_ice+DensityDustProfile[i]*result_dust)/DensityProfile[i]

  return res

u=np.array(np.random.rand(1000000),dtype=np.float32)
PorosityProfile=np.array(np.random.rand(1000000),dtype=np.float32)
DensityIceProfile=np.array(np.random.rand(1000000),dtype=np.float32)
DensityDustProfile=np.array(np.random.rand(1000000),dtype=np.float32)
DensityProfile=np.array(np.random.rand(1000000),dtype=np.float32)
DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI = 250.0, 633.0, 2.513, -2.2e-3, -2.8e-6
IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH =  273.16, 1.843e5, 1.6357e8, 3.5519e9, 1.6670e2,  6.4650e4, 1.6935e6

#don't measure compilation overhead on first call
res=improved_Numba_p(u, PorosityProfile, DensityIceProfile, DensityDustProfile, DensityProfile,DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI,IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH) 
for i in range(1000):
  res=improved_Numba_p(u, PorosityProfile, DensityIceProfile, DensityDustProfile, DensityProfile,DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI,IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH)

print(time.time()-t1)
print(time.time()-t1)
```

**Performance**

```
Arraysize np.random.rand(100)
Numpy             46.8µs
naive Numba       3.1µs
improved Numba:   1.62µs
improved_Numba_p: 17.45µs


#Arraysize np.random.rand(1000000)
Numpy             255.8ms
naive Numba       18.6ms
improved Numba:   6.13ms
improved_Numba_p: 3.54ms
```

**Code dtype=np.float32**

If np.float32 is sufficient you have to explicitly declare all constant values in the function to float32. Otherwise Numba will use float64.

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model='numpy')
def improved_Numba(u, PorosityProfile, DensityIceProfile, DensityDustProfile, DensityProfile):
  DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI = nb.float32(250.0), nb.float32(633.0), nb.float32(2.513), nb.float32(-2.2e-3), nb.float32(-2.8e-6)
  IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH =  nb.float32(273.16), nb.float32(1.843e5), nb.float32(1.6357e8), nb.float32(3.5519e9), nb.float32(1.6670e2),  nb.float32(6.4650e4), nb.float32(1.6935e6)
  res=np.empty(u.shape[0],dtype=u.dtype)

  for i in range(u.shape[0]):
    delta = u[i]-DustJ
    result_dust = DustF+DustG*delta+DustH*delta**2+DustI*(delta**3)

    x= u[i]/IceI
    result_ice = (x**3)*(IceC+IceD*(x**2)+IceE*(x**6))/(nb.float32(1)+IceF*(x**2)+IceG*(x**4)+IceH*(x**8))

    res[i]=(DensityIceProfile[i]*result_ice+DensityDustProfile[i]*result_dust)/DensityProfile[i]

  return res

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,error_model='numpy')
def improved_Numba_p(u, PorosityProfile, DensityIceProfile, DensityDustProfile, DensityProfile):
  res=np.empty((u.shape[0]),dtype=u.dtype)
  DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI = nb.float32(250.0), nb.float32(633.0), nb.float32(2.513), nb.float32(-2.2e-3), nb.float32(-2.8e-6)
  IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH =  nb.float32(273.16), nb.float32(1.843e5), nb.float32(1.6357e8), nb.float32(3.5519e9), nb.float32(1.6670e2),  nb.float32(6.4650e4), nb.float32(1.6935e6)

  for i in nb.prange(u.shape[0]):
    delta = u[i]-DustJ
    result_dust = DustF+DustG*delta+DustH*delta**2+DustI*(delta**3)

    x= u[i]/IceI
    result_ice = (x**3)*(IceC+IceD*(x**2)+IceE*(x**6))/(nb.float32(1)+IceF*(x**2)+IceG*(x**4)+IceH*(x**8))

    res[i]=(DensityIceProfile[i]*result_ice+DensityDustProfile[i]*result_dust)/DensityProfile[i]

  return res
```

**Performance**

```
Arraysize np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
Numpy             29.3µs
improved Numba:   1.33µs
improved_Numba_p: 18µs


Arraysize np.random.rand(1000000).astype(np.float32)
Numpy             117ms
improved Numba:   2.46ms
improved_Numba_p: 1.56ms
```

The comparison to the Cython version provided by @CodeSurgeon isn't really fair because he didn't compile the function with enabled AVX2 and FMA3 instructions. Numba compiles by default with -march=native which enables AVX2 and FMA3 instructions on my Core i7-4xxx.

But this makes sence if you wan't to distribute a compiled Cython version of your code, because it won't run by default on pre Haswell processors (or all Pentium and Celerons) if that optimizations are enabled. Compiling multiple code paths should be possible, but is compiler dependend and more work.

Comment: This looks exciting! I will try compiling my code with the `march=native` option when I get home as well as include a parallel version using cython's `prange`. Will also try to get numba set up on my weird build environment (running all of my code in msys2 on windows to use the convenient prebuilt packages provided by mingw).

Comment: Thanks for the answer that was very helpful, I am generally using arrays that are size 100 hundred so the improved numba seems to be the best in this case but i'll keep in mind the parallel version for future reference :)

Answer (score 4):

I generally agree with the advice presented by @chepner and @juanpa.arrivillaga in the comments. Numpy is a performant library, and it is true that the underlying calculations it performs are written in C. Furthermore, the syntax is clean and it is trivial to apply scalar operations across all elements of a numpy array.

However, there actually is a way to significantly improve the performance of your code with cython thanks to the way your particular algorithm is structured if we use the following assumptions (and can tolerate ugly code):

- Your arrays are all one-dimensional, making iterating over each item in an array extremely trivial. We do not need to replace more difficult numpy functions like `numpy.dot` for example as all operations in your code only combine scalars with matrices.
- While using a `for` loop in python would be unthinkable, iterating over every index is very feasible in cython. Additionally, each item in the final output depends only on the inputs that correspond to that item's index (i.e. the 0th item uses `u[0]`, `PorosityProfile[0]`, etc).
- You are not interested in any of the intermediate arrays, only in the final result returned in your `compute_python` function. Therefore, why waste time allocating memory for all of those intermediate numpy arrays?
- Using `x**y` syntax is surprisingly slow. I use a `gcc` compiler option, `--ffast-math` to improve this significantly. I also use several cython compiler directives to avoid python checks and overhead.
- Creating numpy arrays itself can have python overhead, so I use a combination of typed memoryviews (the preferred, newer syntax anyways) and malloc-ed pointers to create the output array without interacting with python very much (only two lines, getting the output size and the return statement show significant python interaction as seen in the cython annotation files).

Taking all of these considerations into account, here is the modified code. It performs nearly an order of magnitude faster than the naive python version on my laptop.

**sublimation.pyx**

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

def compute_cython(float[:] u, float[:] porosity_profile, 
        float[:] density_ice_profile, float[:] density_dust_profile, 
        float[:] density_profile):    
    cdef:
        float dust_j, dust_f, dust_g, dust_h, dust_i
        float ice_i, ice_c, ice_d, ice_e, ice_f, ice_g, ice_h
        int size, i
        float dt, result_dust, x, dust
        float result_ice_numer, result_ice_denom, result_ice, ice
        float* out

    dust_j, dust_f, dust_g, dust_h, dust_i = \
        250.0, 633.0, 2.513, -2.2e-3, -2.8e-6
    ice_i, ice_c, ice_d, ice_e, ice_f, ice_g, ice_h = \
        273.16, 1.843e5, 1.6357e8, 3.5519e9, 1.6670e2, 6.4650e4, 1.6935e6
    size = len(u)
    out = <float *>malloc(size * sizeof(float))

    for i in range(size):
        dt = u[i] - dust_j
        result_dust = dust_f + (dust_g*dt) + (dust_h*dt**2) + (dust_i*dt**3)
        x = u[i] / ice_i
        result_ice_numer = x**3*(ice_c + ice_d*x**2 + ice_e*x**6)
        result_ice_denom = 1 + ice_f*x**2 + ice_g*x**4 + ice_h*x**8
        result_ice = result_ice_numer / result_ice_denom
        ice = density_ice_profile[i]*result_ice
        dust = density_dust_profile[i]*result_dust
        out[i] = (dust + ice)/density_profile[i]
    return <float[:size]>out
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.core import Extension

def create_extension(ext_name):
    global language, libs, args, link_args
    path_parts = ext_name.split(".")
    path = "./{0}.pyx".format("/".join(path_parts))
    ext = Extension(ext_name, sources=[path], libraries=libs, language=language,
            extra_compile_args=args, extra_link_args=link_args)
    return ext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    libs = []#no external c libraries in this case
    language = "c"#chooses c rather than c++ since no c++ features were used
    args = ["-w", "-O3", "-ffast-math"]#assumes gcc is the compiler
    link_args = []#none here, could use -fopenmp for parallel code
    annotate = True#autogenerates .html files per .pyx
    directives = {#saves typing @cython decorators and applies them globally
        "boundscheck": False,
        "wraparound": False,
        "initializedcheck": False,
        "cdivision": True,
        "nonecheck": False,
    }

    ext_names = [
        "sublimation",
    ]

    extensions = [create_extension(ext_name) for ext_name in ext_names]
    setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
            extensions, 
            annotate=annotate, 
            compiler_directives=directives,
        )
    )
```

**main.py**

```
import numpy as np
import sublimation as sub

def compute_python(u, PorosityProfile, DensityIceProfile, DensityDustProfile, DensityProfile):
    DustJ, DustF, DustG, DustH, DustI = 250.0, 633.0, 2.513, -2.2e-3, -2.8e-6   
    IceI, IceC, IceD, IceE, IceF, IceG, IceH =  273.16, 1.843e5, 1.6357e8, 3.5519e9, 1.6670e2,  6.4650e4, 1.6935e6
    delta = u-DustJ
    result_dust = DustF+DustG*delta+DustH*delta**2+DustI*(delta**3)
    x = u/IceI
    result_ice = (x**3)*(IceC+IceD*(x**2)+IceE*(x**6))/(1+IceF*(x**2)+IceG*(x**4)+IceH*(x**8))
    return (DensityIceProfile*result_ice+DensityDustProfile*result_dust)/DensityProfile

size = 100
u = np.random.rand(size).astype(np.float32)
porosity = np.random.rand(size).astype(np.float32)
ice = np.random.rand(size).astype(np.float32)
dust = np.random.rand(size).astype(np.float32)
density = np.random.rand(size).astype(np.float32)

"""
Run these from the terminal to out the performance!
python3 -m timeit -s "from main import compute_python, u, porosity, ice, dust, density" "compute_python(u, porosity, ice, dust, density)"
python3 -m timeit -s "from main import sub, u, porosity, ice, dust, density" "sub.compute_cython(u, porosity, ice, dust, density)"
python3 -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; from main import sub, u, porosity, ice, dust, density" "np.asarray(sub.compute_cython(u, porosity, ice, dust, density))"

The first command tests the python version. (10000 loops, best of 3: 45.5 usec per loop)
The second command tests the cython version, but returns just a memoryview object. (100000 loops, best of 3: 4.63 usec per loop)
The third command tests the cython version, but converts the result to a ndarray (slower). (100000 loops, best of 3: 6.3 usec per loop)
"""
```

Let me know if there are any unclear parts in my explanation for how this answer works, and I hope it helps!

---

**Update 1:**

Unfortunately, I was unable to get MSYS2 and numba (which depends on LLVM) to play nice with each other, so I could not do any direct comparisons. However, following @max9111's advice, I added `-march=native` to the `args` list in my `setup.py` file; however, the timings did not significantly differ from before.

From [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49804276), it appears that there is some overhead in the automatic conversion between numpy arrays and typed memoryviews that goes on both in the initial function call (and in the return statement as well if you convert the result back). Reverting back to using a function signature like this:

```
ctypedef np.float32_t DTYPE_t
def compute_cython_np(
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] u, 
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] porosity_profile, 
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] density_ice_profile, 
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] density_dust_profile, 
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] density_profile):
```

saves me about 1us per call, cutting it down to about 3.6us instead of 4.6us, which is somewhat significant, especially if the function is to be called many times. **Of course, if you plan to call the function many times, it might be more efficient instead to just pass in two-dimensional numpy arrays instead, saving significant python function call overhead and amortizing the cost of `numpy array -> typed memoryview` conversion.** Furthermore, it might be interesting to use numpy structured arrays, which can be transformed in cython into a typed memoryview of structs, as this might put all of the data closer together in the cache and speed memory access times.

As a final note as promised in the comments earlier, here is a version using `prange` that takes advantage of parallel processing. Note that this can only be used with typed memoryviews as python's GIL must be released within a prange loop (and compiled using the `-fopenmp` flag for `args` and `link_args`:

```
from cython.parallel import prange
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
def compute_cython_p(float[:] u, float[:] porosity_profile, 
        float[:] density_ice_profile, float[:] density_dust_profile, 
        float[:] density_profile):    
    cdef:
        float dust_j, dust_f, dust_g, dust_h, dust_i
        float ice_i, ice_c, ice_d, ice_e, ice_f, ice_g, ice_h
        int size, i
        float dt, result_dust, x, dust
        float result_ice_numer, result_ice_denom, result_ice, ice
        float* out

    dust_j, dust_f, dust_g, dust_h, dust_i = \
        250.0, 633.0, 2.513, -2.2e-3, -2.8e-6
    ice_i, ice_c, ice_d, ice_e, ice_f, ice_g, ice_h = \
        273.16, 1.843e5, 1.6357e8, 3.5519e9, 1.6670e2, 6.4650e4, 1.6935e6
    size = len(u)
    out = <float *>malloc(size * sizeof(float))

    for i in prange(size, nogil=True):
        dt = u[i] - dust_j
        result_dust = dust_f + (dust_g*dt) + (dust_h*dt**2) + (dust_i*dt**3)
        x = u[i] / ice_i
        result_ice_numer = x**3*(ice_c + ice_d*x**2 + ice_e*x**6)
        result_ice_denom = 1 + ice_f*x**2 + ice_g*x**4 + ice_h*x**8
        result_ice = result_ice_numer / result_ice_denom
        ice = density_ice_profile[i]*result_ice
        dust = density_dust_profile[i]*result_dust
        out[i] = (dust + ice)/density_profile[i]
    return <float[:size]>out
```

---

**Update 2:**

Following the very useful additional advice from @max9111 in the comments, I switched over all of the `float[:]` declarations in my code to `float[::1]`. The significance of this is that it allows the data to be stored contiguously  and cython would not need to worry about the presence of a stride between elements. This allows SIMD Vectorization, which dramatically further optimizes the code. Below are the updated timings, which are generated using the following commands:

```
python3 -m timeit -s "from main import compute_python, u, porosity, ice, dust, density" "compute_python(u, porosity, ice, dust, density)"
python3 -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; from main import sub, u, porosity, ice, dust, density" "np.asarray(sub.compute_cython(u, porosity, ice, dust, density))"
python3 -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; from main import sub, u, porosity, ice, dust, density" "np.asarray(sub.compute_cython_p(u, porosity, ice, dust, density))"

size = 100
python: 44.7 usec per loop
cython serial: 4.44 usec per loop
cython parallel: 111 usec per loop
cython serial contiguous: 3.83 usec per loop
cython parallel contiguous: 116 usec per loop

size = 1000
python: 167 usec per loop
cython serial: 16.4 usec per loop
cython parallel: 115 usec per loop
cython serial contiguous: 8.24 usec per loop
cython parallel contiguous: 111 usec per loop

size = 10000
python: 1.32 msec per loop
cython serial: 128 usec per loop
cython parallel: 142 usec per loop
cython serial contiguous: 55.5 usec per loop
cython parallel contiguous: 150 usec per loop

size = 100000
python: 19.5 msec per loop
cython serial: 1.21 msec per loop
cython parallel: 691 usec per loop
cython serial contiguous: 473 usec per loop
cython parallel contiguous: 274 usec per loop

size = 1000000
python: 211 msec per loop
cython serial: 12.3 msec per loop
cython parallel: 5.74 msec per loop
cython serial contiguous: 4.82 msec per loop
cython parallel contiguous: 1.99 msec per loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed answer, In this specific case Numba does seem to be the best option but your code will certainly be useful for other parts of the code. I learned a lot :)

Comment: @AnthonyLethuillier Definitely agree with that, Numba is the cleanest, best bet for your problem. I think I will still try to add some more info to this answer so it is more complete for future readers anyways

Comment: You are missing a quite significant point. I didn't kow it either until I read this excellent answer from @ead. You have to explicitly declare the input array as contignious to enable SIMD-vectorization. Numba recognizes this automaticlly at compile time without explicit type information, but doesn't if you declare the types explicitly. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49059414/4045774 This can also be the reason why march-native doesn't show the expected speedup.

Comment: Testing with size = 1000000 gives me (9.3 ms for your version, 5.1 ms with declaring contigous arrays, 4.4ms with contigous arrays and march=native)

Comment: @max9111 Thanks for this info, definitely did not know that! I guess I better add a second update :)